# How can I get data from JavaScript in webview?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swift

This is my JavaScript and HTML in iOS Project:

```
<input type="file" id="upload">
```

and I open the HTML in my webview

```
func webload() {
    let myPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")

    webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: myPath!)!))
}
```

but how can I get the file on My iOS APP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the javascript into the webview using 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: